# JavaScript Module Pattern with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I have an application which currently uses AJAX for CRUD operations on a simple `Person` object.  The following script works fine, but I'm looking for some pointers on how to structure my code.  Currently, I have four methods for CRUD operations, and I'll extend my `person` module as needed, but I was hoping to get an idea of whether or not this is a nice way to manage code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            //open the modal
            //the update, delete and insert functions come from boxes present in a modal not shown
            $('#openModal').click(function () {
                $('#contact').modal();
            });
            //insert
            $('#btnSavePerson').click(function () {
                //is it a good idea to have the data objects inside all of these functions?    
                var data = {
                    personId: $('#tbPersonId').val(),
                    firstName: $('#tbFirstName').val(),
                    lastName: $('#tbLastName').val()
                };
                person.insert(data);
            });

            //delete
            $('#btnDeletePerson').click(function () {
                var personId = $('#tbDelete').val();
                person.remove(personId);
            });

            //update
            $('#btnUpdatePerson').click(function () {
                var data = {
                    personId: $('#tbPersonId').val(),
                    firstName: $('#tbFirstName').val(),
                    lastName: $('#tbLastName').val()
                };
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                person.update(data);
            });
            //get
            $('#getPeople').click(function () {
                person.get();
            });
            //*********************person module

            var person = (function () {
                //the ajax object will be passed and shared between
                //the functions here (type and dataType dont change in this example)
                var ajax = {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "",
                    data: {},
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: {},
                    error: {}
                }

                //************ insert
                function insert(data) {
                    ajax.url = '../Service.asmx/InsertPerson';
                    ajax.success = function () {
                        console.log('success before setTimeout');
                        var successMessage = $('<div>').text('Successfully added to the database...')
                                                       .css('color', 'green')
                                                       .attr('id', 'success');
                        $('.modal-body').append(successMessage);
                        window.setTimeout(function () {
                            $('.modal-body').each(function () {
                                $(this).val('');
                            });
                            $('#contact').modal('hide');
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                    ajax.data = JSON.stringify(data);
                    ajax.error = function (xhr, ajaxOptions) {
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                        console.log(ajaxOptions);
                    };
                    $.ajax(ajax);
                }
                //************* delete
                function remove(data) {
                    ajax.url = '../Service.asmx/DeletePerson';
                    console.log('working string: ');
                    var obj = { personId: data };
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
                    ajax.data = JSON.stringify(obj);
                    console.log(ajax.data);
                    ajax.success = function () {
                        console.log('person successfully deleted');
                        var successMessage = $('<div>').text('Person successfully deleted from the database')
                                                       .css('color', 'red');
                        $('.modal-body').append(successMessage);
                        window.setTimeout(function () {
                            $('.modal-body input').each(function () {
                                $(this).val('');
                            });
                            $('#contact').modal('hide');
                        }, 1000);
                    };
                    ajax.error = function (xhr, ajaxOptions) {
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                        console.log(ajaxOptions);
                    }
                    $.ajax(ajax);
                }
                //*************** update
                function update(data) {
                    ajax.url = '../Service.asmx/UpdatePerson',
                    ajax.data = JSON.stringify(data),
                    ajax.success = function () {
                        console.log('update was successful');
                        var successMessage = $('<div>').text('Record successfully updated...')
                                                       .css('color', 'green');
                        $('modal-body').append(successMessage);
                        window.setTimeout(function () {
                            $('.modal-body input').each(function () {
                                $(this).val('');
                            });
                            $('#contact').modal('hide');
                        }, 1000);
                    };
                    ajax.error = function (xhr, ajaOptions) {
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                    };
                    $.ajax(ajax);
                };
                //************** get
                function get() {
                    //****** appropriate to have this function here?
                    function style(json) {
                        json = $.parseJSON(json);
                        var $personArray = [];
                        for (var obj in json) {
                            var $person = $('<div>').addClass('person');
                            for (var prop in json[obj]) {
                                var label = $('<span>').text(prop).addClass('badge pull-left').appendTo($person);
                                var propertyData = $('<span>').text(json[obj][prop]).addClass('pull-right').appendTo($person);
                            }
                            $personArray.push($person);
                        }
                        return $personArray;
                    }
                    ajax.url = '../Service.asmx/GetPersons';
                    ajax.success = function (data) {
                        data = data.d;
                        console.log('ajax successful');
                        $('body').append(style(data));
                    };
                    ajax.error = function (xhr, ajaxOptions) {
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                        console.log(ajaxOptions);
                    }
                    $.ajax(ajax);
                }
                //*********** public methods
                return {
                    insert: insert,
                    remove: remove,
                    update: update,
                    get: get
                };

            })();

        });
```

HTML in case someone wants to see it:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">ui</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar">
                </span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

                    <li><a id="openModal"  href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <p id="getPeople" class="btn btn-block">get them peoples</p>
    <div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="diaglog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h2>contact: </h2>    

               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
               The improtant information from the database is going to be displayed here. 
               <span class="label label-success">Person ID: </span><input id="tbPersonId" class="warning" /><br />
               <span class="label label-success">First Name:</span><input id="tbFirstName" /><br />
               <span class="label label-success">Last Name: </span><input id="tbLastName" /><br />
               <span class="label label-danger">Delete box: </span><input id="tbDelete" />
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-default" id="modalClose" >Close</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSavePerson">Save changes</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger"  id="btnDeletePerson">Delete person</a>
                <a class="btn btn-block"   id="btnUpdatePerson">Update Person</a>

               </div>
               </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right, I'm on a break, so this is just a few pointers to help you along. I'll probably get back to this answer and add some more details in days to come...

the first thing I noticed is that you declared your `person` module somewhere half-way your `ready` callback function. Though the variable `person` will be hoisted to the top of the scope the IIFE (Immediatly invoked function expression) that assigns it *cannot be hoisted*. It's an expression, so your code evaluates to:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var person;
    //some code, using person as a module
    person = (function()
    {
    }());//assignment happens here!
});
```

Though it's very unlikely this will cause problems, it's generally a good idea to move the assignment to the top of the scope:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var person = (function()
    {
    }());
    //rest of your code here...
});
```

Another thing that sort of annoys me is your use of `window`:

```
window.setTimeout
```

But at the same time, you're using:

```
console.log();
```

without the `window` reference. That's inconsistent and, if anything, quite redundant. JS resolves the `window` name in the same way as it resolves `console` or `setTimeout`: it scans the current scope, if it can't find the name there, it moves up to a higher scope until it reaches the global namespace/scope.
As you may know, the global NS is, effectively an object that has no name. (try `console.log(this === window)` in your console). This object has a property, called `window`, which is nothing more than a circular reference to this nameless object. Hence `console.log(this.window === window); console.log(this.window === this)` will both log true. As a result `setTimeout` will be very, very marginally *faster* than `window.setTimeout` anyway, so I'd suggest you loose the `window` where you can.

Next: the `person` module isn't exactly *stand-alone*, in it, you assume `$` to be the jQuery object, and you expect it to be defined in a higher scope. I wouldn't do that. Here's why:

```
var dependency = {foo: function()
{
    return 'bar';
}};
var unsafeModule = (function()
{
    return { getBar : dependency.foo};
}());
unsafeModule.getBar();//returns bar, fine...
dependency = 213;
unsafeModule.getBar();//ERROR
```

A better, safer approach would be:

```
var dependency = {foo: function()
{
    return 'bar';
}};
var saferModule = (function(d)
{
    return { getBar : d.foo};
}(dependency));
```

By passing a reference to the object my module, that object remains in scope, and my module will continue to work just fine 'n dandy, no matter how many times the `dependency` variable gets reassigned.
But even better would be:

```
var dependency = {foo: function()
{
    return 'bar';
}};
var saferModule = (function(d)
{
    var mod = {setter: function(dep)
    {
        d = dep;
        this.getBar = d.foo;
        delete (this.setter);
        return this;
    }};

    if (d === undefined) return mod;
    return mod.setter(d);
}());//no dependency passed!
d.setter(dependency);//sets dependency
d.getBar();//works
```

When we apply this logic to your module, you can safely move the `person` module declaration to another file, or outside of the `$(document)ready` callback's scope:

```
var person = (function()
{
    var mod = { remove : function(){},
                get : function(){}};//declare your module
    return {init: function($)
    {
        var p;
        if($ instanceof jQuery)
        {
            delete(this.init);//unset init method
            for (p in mod)
            {//copy module properties into person
                this[p] = mod[p];
            }
            return this;
        }
        throw {message: 'Module needs jQ to work', code: 666};
    }};
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    person.init($);//pass jQ ref to module, it'll init itself.
});
```

Lastly, a side-note. You're trying to implement the module pattern. That's good, but a module requires a closure. You can use closures all over the place to avoid, for example, excessive DOM queries.
For example:

```
$('#openModal').click(function () {
    $('#contact').modal();
});
```

Now each time I click on `$('#openModal')`, the callback function gets called. this function will query the DOM, because `$('#contact')` is a DOM selector. If I click this element 10 times, the DOM will be queried 10 times. A closure can reduce this:

```
$('#openModal').click((function(contact)
{
    return function()
    {
        contact.modal();//use ref in scope, no more DOM lookups required
    };
}($('#contact')));//pass DOM ref here, query dom once
```

These sort of, seemingly trivial, optimizations are easy, but can make a difference the bigger your script gets, and the more interactive your site has to be.

---

Ok, another update. I've noticed you write code like this:

```
$('#getPeople').click(function()
{
    person.get();
});
```

This is typical jQ code: passing an anonymous function to the event handler. When a callback function (ie the anonymous function) merely calls another function, wouldn't it be easier, shorter *and* more efficient to just pass a reference to the function you need in the first place?

```
$('#getPeople').click(person.get);
```

It'll do pretty much the same thing, is shorter to write and saves on a pointless function object.
The only downside being: you're losing the call-context (within the `person.get` function `this` won't point to `person` anymore). So I had a look at your `person.get` function. I'll paste it here, with some comments. I'll address some issues further down

```
function get()
{
    //****** appropriate to have this function here?
    // NO, this function will be redeclared each time person.get is called
    //it should be defined somewhere else, in a higher scope
    function style(json)
    {
        json = $.parseJSON(json);
        var $personArray = [];
        for (var obj in json)
        {//still best to filter a for-in loop
            var $person = $('<div>').addClass('person');//again, DOM query?
            for (var prop in json[obj])
            {//I can't see where you're using the label var...
                var label = $('<span>').text(prop).addClass('badge pull-left').appendTo($person);
                var propertyData = $('<span>').text(json[obj][prop]).addClass('pull-right').appendTo($person);
            }
            $personArray.push($person);
        }
        return $personArray;
    }
    ajax.url = '../Service.asmx/GetPersons';
    ajax.success = function (data)
    {//this callback can be reused, too
        data = data.d;
        console.log('ajax successful');
        $('body').append(style(data));//avoid DOM access!
    };
    ajax.error = function (xhr, ajaxOptions)
    {//another callback to be avoided!
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(ajaxOptions);
    }
    $.ajax(ajax);
}
```

So, let's consider what the `get` function actually *needs* to do its job:

- a `style` function
- a couple of callbacks (`success` and `onerror`) for the `ajax` object literal, and its own URL
- A couple of DOM elements, for example the `$('body')`. That's a pretty static element, I do believe.

So instead of getting all these objects, why not define/declare them when we're creating our `get` function, and reuse them every time this function is called? Instead of declaring `function get` inside the IIFE that returns the `person` module, we could write something like:

```
var get = (function(body)
{
    var successCallback, style,
        errorCallback = function(xhr, ajaxOptions)
    {//or declare as local var to function
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(ajaxOptions);
    };
    successCallback = function (data)
    {
        console.log('ajax successful');
        //use DOM reference, parse it here already... SRP!
        body.append(style($.parseJSON(data.d)));
    };
    style = function(json)
    {
        var personArray = [], obj, prop, person;//declare at top of scope
        for (obj in json)
        {//I do hope this isn't an array!
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(obj))
            {//best to check, still
                person = $('<div class="person"'>);//avoid addClass call
                for (prop in json[obj])
                {
                    if (json[obj].hasOwnProperty(prop))
                    {//no point in assigning return val to vars you do not use
                        $('<span class="badge pull-left">')
                                 .text(prop).appendTo(person);
                        $('<span class="pull-right">')
                                 .text(json[obj][prop]).appendTo(person);
                    }
                }
                personArray.push(person);
            }
        }
        return personArray;
    };
    //the actual get function:
    return function()
    {
        ajax.url = '../Service.asmx/GetPersons';
        ajax.success = successCallback;
        ajax.error = errorCallback;
        return $.ajax(ajax);
    };
}($('body')));//either pass as argument
```

Now what I've done here is sort-of created a get *module* within the main *person* module. You can (and probably eventually will) work some more on this, since all of your person module functions perform ajax requests, you might add a more generic *`getAjax`* function that you choose not to expose.
A function that gouverns the `ajax` object, and keeps track of the callbacks and urls each function in the module requires, and that sets the ajax object accordingly:

```
var doAjax = function()
{
    var ajax = {},//your ajax object literal
    callers = {get: {url: '../Service.asmx/GetPersons',
                     success: function(){},
                     error: function(){}},
               insert: {url: '../Service.asmx/InsertPerson',
                        success: function(){}},
               default: {url: 'some/default',
                         success: function(){}}
    };
    return function(data,caller)
    {
        var settings,p;
        caller = caller || 'default';
        settings = callers[caller] || callers.default;
        for (p in settings)
        {
            if (settings.hasOwnProperty(p)) ajax[p] = settings[p];
        }
        return $.ajax(ajax);
    };
}());
```

Now all your module functions can just call this function like so:

```
doAjax(myData, 'insert');
//or
doAjax(undefined, 'get');
```

Oh, and this code would go here:

```
var person = (function()
{
    var doAjax = (function(){}());//in module!
}());
```

Comment: This is exactly the type of stuff that I was looking for.  I'll be honest, some of the concepts here are a little outside of my league at first blush, but this gives me a good idea of what a BETTER idea would be and that's what I was looking for.  I'll leave this unchecked as the answer until you're finished adding whatever you think it necessary.  Great stuff, gracias!

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: I've added some more details, mainly on the `get` function you wrote. I did mention context (`this`) bindings. This concept is, to many, quite difficult to understand at first, [perhaps refer to MDN for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: danke this is all great stuff.